# Find where 2 Gps Radials intercept

Tags: c#, gps

I can't seem to nail the bug I apparently have made in this code. I have a GpsPosition struct which among other things stores the Latitude and Longitude internal in the properties LatAsRadian and LonAsRadian (you create the instance using Degrees, but internally it stores in Radians).

In this struct I have multiple methods among one that calculates where 2 radials intercept each other. Source examples on performing this calculation can be found from these links:
- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (Intersection of two paths given start points and bearings)
- ftp://ftp.bartol.udel.edu/anita/amir/My_thesis/Figures4Thesis/CRC_plots/Aviation%20Formulary%20V1.46.pdf (Intersecting radials)

My method (see below) finds a position that is "relative" close to the correct intersection. Using the example values from the first link, I find a GpsPosition that is 4 Nm of track from one of the radials, but 24 Nm from the other (but still these are far beyond simple rounding issues):

```
/// <summary>
///     Calculate where a plotted great cicle arc from this point (along the specified Bearing)
///     intersects another great circle arc specified by its pos and posBearing)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bearing">The bearing of the great cicle arc with its origin in this pos.</param>
/// <param name="arcPos">Pos along the other great cicle arc.</param>
/// <param name="arcBearing">Bearing (direction) of the other great circle arc.</param>
/// <returns>The Point (GpsPosition) where the two specified great circle arcs intersects.</returns>
public GpsPosition GetIntersectionPoint(double bearing, GpsPosition arcPos, double arcBearing)
{
    double bearingRad = bearing*MathUtil.DegToRadFactor;
    double arcBearingRad = arcBearing*MathUtil.DegToRadFactor;

    double sinDeltaLatHalf = Math.Sin((LatAsRadian - arcPos.LatAsRadian)/2d);
    double sinDeltaLonHalf = Math.Sin((LonAsRadian - arcPos.LonAsRadian)/2d);

    double dst12 = 2d*Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(sinDeltaLatHalf*sinDeltaLatHalf +
                                          Math.Cos(LatAsRadian)*Math.Cos(arcPos.LatAsRadian)*
                                          sinDeltaLonHalf*sinDeltaLonHalf));

    double crsA =
        Math.Acos((Math.Sin(arcPos.LatAsRadian) - Math.Sin(LatAsRadian)*Math.Cos(dst12))/Math.Sin(dst12)*
                  Math.Cos(LatAsRadian));
    double crsB =
        Math.Acos((Math.Sin(LatAsRadian) - Math.Sin(arcPos.LatAsRadian)*Math.Cos(dst12))/Math.Sin(dst12)*
                  Math.Cos(arcPos.LatAsRadian));

    double crs12, crs21;
    if (Math.Sin(arcPos.LonAsRadian - LonAsRadian) > 0)
    {
        crs12 = crsA;
        crs21 = MathUtil.PI2 - crsB;
    }
    else
    {
        crs12 = MathUtil.PI2 - crsA;
        crs21 = crsB;
    }

    double ang1 = ((bearingRad - crs12 + MathUtil.PI)%MathUtil.PI2) - MathUtil.PI;
    double ang2 = ((crs21 - arcBearingRad + MathUtil.PI)%MathUtil.PI2) - MathUtil.PI;

    if ((Math.Sin(ang1) == 0d) && (Math.Sin(ang2) == 0d))
        return new GpsPosition(double.NaN, double.NaN); // "infinity of intersections"
    if (Math.Sin(ang1)*Math.Sin(ang2) < 0d)
        return new GpsPosition(double.NaN, double.NaN); // "intersection ambiguous"

    double ang3 = Math.Acos(-Math.Cos(ang1)*Math.Cos(ang2) + Math.Sin(ang1)*Math.Sin(ang2)*Math.Cos(dst12));
    double dst13 = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(dst12)*Math.Sin(ang1)*Math.Sin(ang2),
        Math.Cos(ang2) + Math.Cos(ang1)*Math.Cos(ang3));
    double lat3 =
        Math.Asin(Math.Sin(LatAsRadian)*Math.Cos(dst13) +
                  Math.Cos(LatAsRadian)*Math.Sin(dst13)*Math.Cos(bearingRad));
    double dlon = Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(bearingRad)*Math.Sin(dst13)*Math.Cos(LatAsRadian),
        Math.Cos(dst13) - Math.Sin(LatAsRadian)*Math.Sin(lat3));
    double lon3 = ((LonAsRadian + dlon + MathUtil.PI)%MathUtil.PI2) - MathUtil.PI;
    return new GpsPosition(lat3*MathUtil.RadToDegFactor, lon3*MathUtil.RadToDegFactor);
}
```

The code above uses the constants MathUtil.PI defined as Math.PI, and MathUtil.PI2 defined as Math.PI*2d.

Anyone who can spot the bug, or have a C# implementation of this method that works?